# Ionic tabs shows a white background between tabs for a fraction of a second

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have tried to find a solution to this white background problem but after searching and testing all your answers, nothing works.

```
<ion-tab title="News" icon-off="ion-android-earth" icon-on="ion-android-earth" href="#/tab/news">
        <ion-nav-view name="tab-news"></ion-nav-view>
        <ion-view>
            <ion-nav-bar class="hackbg">
            </ion-nav-bar>
        </ion-view>
    </ion-tab>
```

Even with this, I can see the white background for a fraction of a second when I navigate through the tabs which is really annoying if you ask me frowning

I have 4 tabs, 3 of them get dynamic data from an http call, the last tab loads an iframe with a video from YouTube. When I launch the app, and navigate through any of the tabs, I can see the annoying white background. Now, if I click on the 4 tab (the iframe video) the first time, I will also see the white background for a fraction of a second. However, if I navigate to another tab (which that said, I will also see the white background), and I come back to the video tab, I will then NO see the white background anymore. All the other 3 tabs I will always see the white background, independently of the times I visit the tab section.

My individual tabs pages look like the following:

```
<ion-view hide-nav-bar="true" class="hackbg">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive bar-header" align-title="left">
        <h1 class="title">Logo...</h1>
        <div class="buttons pull-right">
            <button ng-click="go1()" class="button button-icon icon  ion-ios7-1"></button>
            <button ng-click="go2()" class="button button-icon icon  ion-ios7-2"></button>
            <button ng-click="go3()" class="button button-icon icon  ion-ios7-3"></button>
            <button class="button button-icon ion-android-more" ng-click="popover.show($event)"></button>
        </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
...
```

As you can see, I have also added the hackbg on the ion-view with the hope that would fix the problem but it didn't.

I have try/catch all over the code to try to see if I have an error somewhere in the code and that's why the white background. However, no luck, I don't see any error anywhere.

If I go to the individual pages from the navigation (e.g. look at buttons like go1(), I do not see any white background). The problem are only related to the tabs.

Ah, my splashscreen also shows the white background for a fraction of a second after it loads my splashscreen. I also went and google all possible solutions but none did the trick. I also went through all the possible answers I could find on stackoverflow but nothing did the trick.

My .run contains the following:

```
 $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        }, 6000
```

I extended the delay to 6000 hoping it will make the white background disappear. It didn't. Interesting thing is that sometimes you see it longer and sometimes extremely fast. It is not consistent.

Does anyone knows another trick I could try to fix this?

Comment: I'm having this same issue as well, Have you been able to find a way ?

Comment: Could it be caused by angular.css.injector?

Comment: Please try to change ion-tabs to transparent

Comment: Does not work..

Comment: same problem here with an old app.
this maybe can solve https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/when-changing-tabs-there-is-a-empty-view-with-white-background-until-the-content-is-rendered/7079/3

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible due to Ionic pages only loads once.

Comment: There should be some way.